# SQL Subqueries Issues

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

My question is to retrieve a shop who sell each item at more than the average market price;

```
SELECT SHOP_NAME, Trade_Name
FROM SELL_ITEM f
WHERE PRICE >
  (SELECT
   AVG(PRICE)
   FROM SELL_ITEM s
   WHERE f.Trade_Name = s.Trade_Name
   GROUP BY TRADE_NAME);
```

This query return me all the shop selling item > than average market price, but how can I filter out those not for each item?

Comment: Is this Mysql, MSSQL, Oracle ...?

Comment: You should include test data and expected result

Comment: Then please remove the tsql tag.

Comment: @JamesJiao I added the tsql tag (twice). Please read the first comment under the chosen answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited ... (missed a nuance the first time)

```
SELECT shop_name FROM
(
    SELECT shop_name, MIN(case when f.price > a.avg_price then 1 else 0 end) AS is_always_higher_than_avg
    FROM SELL_ITEM f 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT avg(price) AS avg_price, trade_name
        FROM sell_item
        GROUP BY trade_name
    ) a
    ON f.trade_name = a.trade_name
    WHERE f.price > a.avg_price
    GROUP BY shop_name
) b
WHERE is_always_higher_than_avg = 1
```

Comment: Able to give an example for MSSQL?

Comment: Your query actually return me the shop_name which has only several item price higher than average but not each item

Comment: Basically the same thing, but a bit more readable I think:  
SELECT shop_name, trade_name FROM
(
 SELECT price, shop_name, trade_name, AVG(price) OVER (PARTITION BY trade_name) AS avg_price
 FROM sell_item
) a
where a.price > a.avg_price

Comment: I missed that you said higher-than-average for EVERY item.  Updated above.